# Append feature maps to intermediate layers of network in PyTorch

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have the following PyTorch network architecture shown below. It takes in the input of size 16x8x2048, and gives an output of size 256x128x3. I have a feature map that I want to append along the channel dimension after every upsampling layer in the below architecture. I would be scaling the feature maps to the appropriate resolution before appending. How can I append these feature maps in the intermediate layers of the network?

```
model = []
model += [Conv2dBlock(2048, 256, 3, 1, 1, norm='bn', activation=activ, pad_type=pad_type)]
model +=  [nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear')] 
model +=  [Conv2dBlock(256, 128, 3, 1, 1, norm='bn', activation=activ, pad_type=pad_type)]
model +=  [nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear')]
model +=  [Conv2dBlock(128, 64, 3, 1, 1, norm='bn', activation=activ, pad_type=pad_type)]                        
model +=  [nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear')] 
model +=  [Conv2dBlock(64, 32, 3, 1, 1, norm='bn', activation=activ, pad_type=pad_type)]
model +=  [nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear')] 
model +=  [Conv2dBlock(32, 32, 3, 1, 1, norm='bn', activation=activ, pad_type=pad_type)]                        
model += [Conv2dBlock(32, 3, 3, 1, 1, norm='none', activation=activ, pad_type=pad_type)]                        
model = nn.Sequential(*model)
```

Comment: Defining your model like this isn't really good practice, primarily because you can't define dynamic input behavior like what you want to do now. You have to define an actual network of class nn.Module, and then write the forward function in the way you want: you call torch.cat on the output of each upsample to add in your extra feature map. Look into how skip connections are defined.

Comment: Thanks! That method worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was just changing the way in which the network is written as pointed out by https://stackoverflow.com/users/10229754/mercury. The following change shows a way in which the network can be written so that is possible to append additional input. In the `forward()` function, the input can be directly appended using `torch.cat()`-

```
conv1 = Conv2dBlock(2063, 256, 3, 1, 1, norm='bn', activation=activ, pad_type=pad_type)
up1 = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear')
conv2 = Conv2dBlock(256, 128, 3, 1, 1, norm='bn', activation=activ, pad_type=pad_type)
up2 = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear')
conv3 = Conv2dBlock(128, 64, 3, 1, 1, norm='bn', activation=activ, pad_type=pad_type)
up3 = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear')
conv4 = Conv2dBlock(64, 32, 3, 1, 1, norm='bn', activation=activ, pad_type=pad_type)
up4 = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear')
conv5 = Conv2dBlock(32, 32, 3, 1, 1, norm='bn', activation=activ, pad_type=pad_type)
conv6 = Conv2dBlock(32, 3, 3, 1, 1, norm='none', activation=activ, pad_type=pad_type)
```